# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" getting this error when doing object detection

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection

import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
>         2 import os
>         3 
>         4 execution_path = os.getcwd()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection__init__.py in
>   ()
>   ----> 1 import cv2
>         2 
>         3 from imageai.Detection.keras_retinanet.models.resnet import resnet50_retinanet
>         4 from imageai.Detection.keras_retinanet.utils.image import read_image_bgr, read_image_array, read_image_stream, preprocess_image,
>   resize_image
>         5 from imageai.Detection.keras_retinanet.utils.visualization import draw_box, draw_caption
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: try
`conda remove opencv` then `pip install opencv`. from your conda terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your DLL location of python (C:\Program Files\Python35\DLLs) in Environment variables of Path.

Comment: means? I didn't understand

Comment: My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >                                                                                                    Add the path as C:\Program Files\Python35\DLLs (or wherever you installed python)